# How to pass an interpolated string/dynamic property in to a Javascript hash?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-data

So I have an event handler that is basically this:

```
function foo(category_key, category_value){
   ...
   person.set({"data-"+category_key:category_value});
   ...
}
```

And soo if I do:

foo("age", 12);

I would want the **set** function to refer to the "data-age" key in that hash...How do I evaluate the key so that "data-age" is referred to and not "category_key"? Putting parentheses around the expression before the colon throws an "invalid property id" error.

It appears I can just make a new Object and pass in something like this:

```
function foo(category_key, category_value){
   ...
   var ob = new Object();
   ob["data-"+category_key] = category_value;
   person.set(ob);
   ...
}
```

But I was wondering if there was a more terse way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I was wondering if there was a more terse way of doing this.

The only way to make it more terse is to use `{}` (an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_Literals)) instead of `new Object()` — and to use shorter variable names.

```
function foo(key, value)
{
    ...
    var ob = {};
    ob['data-'+key] = value;
    person.set(ob);
    ...
}
```

It wouldn't necessarily make the entire body of code shorter, but you could put that logic into a separate function:

```
function bar(k, v)
{
    var o = {};
    o[k] = v;
    // or o['data'+k] = v;
    return o;
}

function foo(key, value)
{
    ...
    person.set(bar('data-'+key, value));
    // or person.set(bar(key, value));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ECMAScript 5, you can use `Object.defineProperty` ([MDC reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)).